# how to prevent sorting in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

how to prevent sorting in `DataGridView`?

Comment: -1: Next time, please state that you mean Windows Forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Winforms?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; i++)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Columns[i].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you mean sorting in a WPF DataGrid: Set `CanUserSortColumns="False"`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are talking about web page grid view

`<asp:GridView                   AllowPaging=false ...`

Answer (score 1):

Or if it's a WinForms DataGridView you can set the sortmode of the columns as:

```
Column1.SortMode = NotSortable
```